In MySQL there is no difference between A and the Danish letter Å
I have a column in a table where the value is only a letter. The column name is 'place'. When selecting everything from the table grouped by 'place', the letter A and the Danish letter Å is placed together. Why is that?
The encoding for the table is utf8mb3_general_ci and header of the PHP script is set to utf8.
I have tried to change the header of the PHP to iso-8859-1 with no luck.

Because the encoding for the table is utf8mb3_general_ci. If you want sorting that follows the Danish alphabet rules, use utf8mb3_danish_ci instead. The PHP headers charset is irrelevant.

Perhaps you want utf8_danish_ci, which puts ring-A even after z.?  https://mysql.rjweb.org/utf8_collations.html

you must set rhe colation of the table. this set set sort order
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    l CHAR(1),
    c INT
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT  COLLATE=latin1_danish_ci;


insert into my_table VALUES ( 'A' ,1 ), ( 'Å' , 1);


select l,sum(c) from my_table group by l;

result
l   sum(c)
A   1
Å   1

sample https://dbfiddle.uk/JVaOtG3W

The collation is already utf8mb3_general_ci so that probably means the encoding us utf8mb3 so setting a latin1 collation might not work

You may want switch to utf8mb4 charset and utf8mb4_bin collation for supporting international characters.
ALTER DATABASE `<db name>` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;

ALTER TABLE `<table>` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;


The _bin collations give no case folding nor accent stripping.
